Set Custome PaperSize of Printer into CrystalReportViewer in C#
I want to set the Custome PaperSize of the Printer into CrystalReportViewer>Print Report>Preferences>Advance>Paper Size in C#.
I tried this solution But it can't be set to "9x6".
9x6" I created this in the print server properties of the Printer.
But it can't be set into CrystalReportViewer>Print Report>Preferences>Advance>Paper Size
I want to Set PaperSize ="9x6" the in PaperSize DropDown.
private void LoadReport()
{
    string customPaperSizeName = "9x6";

    int customPaperSizeID = GetCustomPaperSizeID(customPaperSizeName);

    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
    report.Load("WithdrawalAdvice.rpt");

    report.PrintOptions.PaperSize = (CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)customPaperSizeID;

    crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = report;

}

static int GetCustomPaperSizeID(string paperSizeName)
{
    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

    // Loop through available paper sizes for the default printer
    foreach (PaperSize size in printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes)
    {
        if (size.PaperName.Equals(paperSizeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return size.RawKind; // Return the PaperSize ID (RawKind)
        }
    }

    // Return -1 if the custom paper size is not found
    return -1;
}

